# Why BINARY function doesnt work in SELECT statment

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am a little bit confusing in using BINARY function in PLSQL and I am not sure if this function even exist in PLSQL since I am new in `PLSQL Programming`
I want to return `0` or `1` depend if project number is alredy taken or not

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM projects WHERE BINARY CustomName = p_number;
```

And here is my function

```
FUNCTION CHECK_PROJECT_NUMBER(p_number NUMBER)
 RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
  rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  /*CHECK IF PROJECT NUMBER IS TAKEN*/
  BEGIN
  OPEN rc FOR
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM projects WHERE BINARY CustomName = p_number;
  RETURN rc;
END CHECK_PROJECT_NUMBER;
```

The error which I get is following

```
Error(869,56): PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Where did I made mistake and what I miss here ?

Comment: Did you find any such function in the SQL manual? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/book-index.html

Comment: Still not find any solution

Comment: But that answers the question, doesn't it? The keyword `BINARY` that you used does not represent any supplied function, as you could have checked for yourself by looking in the SQL manual. That is the reason why you got an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a such function (`BINARY`) - its a datatype.
There is also a `boolean` datatype but it is not used in `sql` (just in `plsql`).

Also, I do not see any need for `cursor` for this function, so

I would rewrite it like this:

```
FUNCTION CHECK_PROJECT_NUMBER(p_number NUMBER)
 RETURN NUMBER IS 
   cnt number:=0;
  BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) into cnt FROM projects WHERE CustomName = 
   p_number;
   if cnt>0 then 
      cnt:=1;  
   end if;
  RETURN cnt;
END CHECK_PROJECT_NUMBER;
```

This function will return `1` if project number is found and `0` otherwise.